# Computing skew in Hive?

Tags: statistics, hive

[This paper](http://www.exp-platform.com/Documents/2014%20experimentersRulesOfThumb.pdf) defines sample skew as

> s = E[X-E(X)]^3 / [Var(X)]^3/2

What's the easiest way to compute this in Hive?

I imagine a two pass algorithm: 1 gets E(X) and Var(X), the other computes E[X-(X)]^3 and rolls it up.

Comment: Maybe one can adapt streaming algorithms: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithms_for_calculating_variance#Higher-order_statistics

Answer (score 1):

I think you are on the right track with a two step approach, especially if you are strictly using Hive. Here is one way to accomplish this in two steps or one query and one subquery:

1. Calculate E(X) using the OVER () clause so we can avoid aggregating the data (this is so we can later calculate E[X-E(X)]):

   ```
   select x, avg(x) over () as e_x  
   from table;
   ```
2. Using the above as a subquery, calculate Var(x) and E[X-E(X)] which will aggregate the data and produce the final statistic:

   ```
   select pow(avg(x - e_x), 3)/sqrt(pow(variance(x), 3))
   from (select x, avg(x) over () as e_x 
         from table) tb
   ;
   ```

Answer (score 0):

The above formula isn't correct at least for Pearson's skew.

The following works at least with Impala:

```
with d as (select somevar as x from yourtable where what>2),
agg as (select avg(x) as m,STDDEV_POP(x) as s,count(*) as n from d),
sk as (select avg(pow(((x-m)/s),3)) as skew from d,agg)
select skew,m,s,n from agg,sk;
```

I tested it via:

```
with dual as (select 1.0 as x),
d as (select 1*x as x from dual union select 2*x from dual union select 4*x from dual union select 8*x from dual union select 16*x from dual union select 32*x from dual), -- This generates 1,2,4,8,16,32
agg as (select avg(x) as m,STDDEV_POP(x) as s,count(*) as n from d),
sk as (select avg(pow(((x-m)/s),3)) as skew from d,agg)
select skew,m,s,n from agg,sk;
```

And it gives the same answer as R:

```
require(moments)
skewness(c(1,2,4,8,16,32)) #gives 1.095221
```

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skewness#Pearson.27s_moment_coefficient_of_skewness